# javascript fibonacci memoization

Tags: javascript, recursion, fibonacci

To calculate the nth term of the fibonacci sequence, I have the familiar recursive function:

```
var fibonacci = function(index){
    if(index<=0){ return 0; }
    if(index===1){ return 1; }
    if(index===2){ return 2; }

    return fibonacci(index-2) + fibonacci(index-1);
}
```

This works as expected. Now, I am trying to store calculated indices in an object:

```
var results = {
  0: 0,
  1: 1,
  2: 2
};

var fibonacci = function(index){
    if(index<=0){ return 0; }
    if(index===1){ return 1; }
    if(index===2){ return 2; }

    if(!results[index]){
        results[index] = fibonacci(index-2) + fibonacci(index-1);
    }
}
```

I know this isn't actually increasing performance since I'm not accessing the results object, but I wanted to check first if my results object was being populated correctly before memoizing. Unfortunately, it isn't. For fibonacci(9), I get:

```
Object {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: NaN, 5: NaN, 6: NaN, 7: NaN, 8: NaN, 9: NaN}
```

Why am I getting NaN for indices past 3?

Comment: Because your function doesn't return anything when index > 2.

Comment: @Juhana Oh man I'm silly. Thank you. Can you submit an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but if you are prepopulating the `results` array, then why do you also need to explicitly test for `index` within the function? Also, `fib(2)` is `1` I believe.

Comment: Following up on the previous comment, you'd be best off simply removing `2` from the cache and removing `if(index===2){ return 2; }` from the code.  The Fibonacci sequence is, depending upon who you ask, either `0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, ...` or `1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, ...`.  Notice that in either case there are two `1`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to close the loop on this answer by posting @Juhana's comment:

"Because your function doesn't return anything when index > 2"

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution using "Helper Method Recursion":

```js
function fib(n) {
  const memorize = {};

  function helper(n) {
    if (n in memorize) return memorize[n];
    if (n < 3) return 1;
    return memorize[n] = helper(n - 1) + helper(n - 2);
  }

  return helper(n);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is my solution:

```js
function fib(n, res = [0, 1, 1]) {
    if (res[n]) {
        return res[n];
    }

    res[n] = fib(n - 1, res) + fib(n - 2, res);
    return res[n];
}

console.log(fib(155));
```

Answer (score 3):

The recursive Fibonacci consume too much processing power which is not good for application. to improve this we use **Memoization**. which keeps the computed result store in Array. so next when the same value comes it will simply return the Stored value from the computed Array.

```js
function memoizeFibonacci(element, memo = {}) {
  if (element < 3) return 1;
  if (element in memo) return memo[element];

  memo[element] = memoizeFibonacci(element - 1, memo) + memoizeFibonacci(element - 2, memo);

  return memo[element];
}
let a = 15;
console.log('Memoize febonaci', memoizeFibonacci(a));
```

Comment: It's strange that you spell "Fibonacci" correctly in the text but not the code...

Answer (score 1):

```js
const f = (n, memo = [0, 1, 1]) => memo[n] ? memo[n] : (memo[n] = f(n - 1, memo) + f(n - 2, memo)) && memo[n]

console.log(f(70))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here're my solutions

**With Memoization (Dynamic Programming) (Time complexity approximately O(n))**

```
const results = {}

function fib(n) {
    if (n <= 1) return n

    if (n in results) {
        return results[n]
    }
    else {
        results[n] = fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1)
    }
    return results[n]

}

console.log(fib(100))
```

**Without Memoization (Time complexity approximately O(2^n))**

```
function fib(n) {
    if (n <= 1) return n

    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)

}

console.log(fib(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my object orientated attempt.

```js
var memofib = {
    memo : {},
    fib : function(n) {
        
        if (n === 0) {
            return 0;
        } else if (n === 1) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            
            if(this.memo[n]) return this.memo[n];
            
            return this.memo[n] = this.fib(n - 1) + this.fib(n - 2);
        }
    }
};


console.log(memofib.fib(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution achieving memoization using a non-recursive approach.

```
// The Fibonacci numbers.
// 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, ……..

function fibonacci(n) {
  const map = new Map(); // Objects can also be used
  map.set(0,1); // seed value for f(0)
  map.set(1,1); // seed value for f(1)
  for(let i=2; i < n - 1; i++) {
    const result = map.get(i - 1) + map.get(i - 2);
    map.set(i,result);
  }
  return map.get(n - 2);
}

console.log(fibonacci(20)); // 4181
```

Answer (score -1):

I have added some additions.

```
var results = {};

var fibonacci = function (index) {
   if (index <= 0) return 0;

   if (index == 1 || index == 2)  return 1;

   return fibonacci(index - 2) + fibonacci(index - 1);
};

for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  results[i] = fibonacci(i);
}

console.log(results);
```

Comment: This answer does not address the OP's desire to memoize intermediate results.